# native library for attach API not available in this JRE

Tags: java, junit, gradle, jmock

I am attempting to build a new project with gradle, junit, and jmock. When I run my build, I get this stack trace:

```
com.heavyweightsoftware.daybook.ws.TypeCodeWsTest STANDARD_ERROR
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Native library for Attach API not available
 in this JRE
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.ru
nTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.ex
ecute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.p
rocessTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.process
TestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionD
ispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionD
ispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(Con
textClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocat
ionHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestCl
ass(TestWorker.java:106)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionD
ispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionD
ispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(Messa
geHub.java:360)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.
onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableE
xecutorImpl.java:40)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no attach in java.library.path
        ... 14 more
Gradle Test Executor 1 finished executing tests.

com.heavyweightsoftware.daybook.ws.TypeCodeWsTest > testGetTypeCodes FAILED
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.heavyweightsoftware.daybook.ws.TypeCodeWsTest.testGetTypeCodes(Ty
peCodeWsTest.java:40)

        Caused by:
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Native library for Attach API not avail
able in this JRE
            at mockit.internal.startup.AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementati
onFromEmbeddedOnes(AgentLoader.java:78)
            at mockit.internal.startup.AgentLoader.loadAgent(AgentLoader.java:46
)
            at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.verifyInitialization(Startup.java
:172)
            at mockit.Invocations.<clinit>(Invocations.java:26)
            ... 1 more

            Caused by:
            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.tools
.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
 Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
 Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unk
nown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at mockit.internal.startup.AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplemen
tationFromEmbeddedOnes(AgentLoader.java:70)
                ... 4 more
```

So I looked and found these questions: [JMockit ERROR - Native library for Attach API not available in this JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868592/jmockit-error-native-library-for-attach-api-not-available-in-this-jre) and [jmockit: Native library for Attach API not available in this JRE error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961571/jmockit-native-library-for-attach-api-not-available-in-this-jre-error)

And I've made the changes in eclipse, but this error happens even when running outside of eclipse and so it's not the eclipse settings.

Here's the output of java -version from the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\thom\git\daybook\WebServices>java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

This is part of gradle build --info:

```
Executing task ':test' (up-to-date check took 0.193 secs) due to:
  Value of input property 'candidateClassFiles' has changed for task ':test'
Starting process 'Gradle Test Executor 1'. Working directory: C:\Users\thom\git\
daybook\WebServices Command: C:\java\bin\java.exe -Djava.security.manager=jarjar
.org.gradle.process.internal.child.BootstrapSecurityManager -Dfile.encoding=wind
ows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -ea -cp C:\Users\th
om\.gradle\caches\2.4\workerMain\gradle-worker.jar jarjar.org.gradle.process.int
ernal.launcher.GradleWorkerMain 'Gradle Test Executor 1'
Successfully started process 'Gradle Test Executor 1'
Gradle Test Executor 1 started executing tests.
```

Which tells me it's running java from c:\java\bin which is the right install. I looked and this directer has javac in it, which I think confirms that it's a JDK and not a JRE.

Any input, oh wise above wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added c:\java\jre\bin to my path and the build started working again.